# Why does RMQ Topic handler is never triggered?

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.2, request

I'm getting stuck with my Topic Handler in Magento.

I have a working RMQ consumer, I can read message on the Queue, no problem.

Here is the communication.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <topic name="shipmentQueue" request="string" response="string">
        <handler name="shipmentQueueShippingRequestHandler" type="Acme\MessageQueue\RequestHandler\ShippingRequestHandler" method="process"/>
    </topic>
</config>
```

Here is the ShippingRequestHandler class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MessageQueue\RequestHandler;

class ShippingRequestHandler
{
    /**
     * @param string $simpleDataItem
     * @return string
     */
    public function process($simpleDataItem)
    {
        echo __LINE__." $simpleDataItem ";
    }
}
```

And here is my queue_consumer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <consumer
        name="shipmentQueue.consumer"
        queue="shipmentQueue"
        connection="amqp"
        handler="Acme\MessageQueue\Consumer\OrderExport::shippingProcess"/>
</config>
```

The OrderExport::shippingProcess() is correctly triggered, but the topic handler is never ever triggered, why ?

The main problem is that our rmq is sending JSON object and Magento want a String, so I want to process the queue message from JSON To string.

If my RMQ is sending JSON, none of the handler is triggered and I get those in logs :

```
Message has been rejected: Error occurred during message decoding.
Message has been rejected: Message with topic "shipmentQueue" must be an instance of "string"
```

Isn't Magento 2 allowing JSON message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your message handler in either `communication.xml` OR `queue_consumer.xml`.

A handler is a class and method that processes a message. Magento has two ways to define a handler for messages.

- In the `<handler>` element of the module’s communication.xml file
- In the handler attribute of the module’s queue_consumer.xml file

The following conditions determine how these handlers are processed:

- If the consumer in queue_consumer.xml does not have a consumerInstance defined, then the system uses the default consumer: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer. In this case, if the  element contains the handler attribute, then it will be used, and the `<handler>` element in communication.xml will be ignored.
- If the consumer in queue_consumer.xml has a consumerInstance defined, then the specific consumer implementation defines how the handler is used.

<sub>Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/config-mq.html#queueconsumerxml</sub>

Comment: But Magento refuse my message, saying : "main.CRITICAL: Message has been rejected: Error occurred during message decoding." and does not even get to the "shippingProcess" method.

Comment: oki, but do you still define the handler in both places?